# 3.5.1 error can't get just created node by id

Tags: neo4j

EDIT: Just got the same behavior on 3.4

EDIT2: If I remove the disableLosslessIntegers from the connection the issue goes away, but the all integer numbers come back as {low: 20, high:0} type structures which breaks my entire application

The following code works fine on neo4j 3.3 using the 1.7.2 neo4j-driver for node:

```
import {v1 as neo4j} from 'neo4j-driver';

const url: string = process.env.COREDB_URL || '';
const user: string = process.env.COREDB_USERNAME || '';
const password: string = process.env.COREDB_PASSWORD || '';

const driver = neo4j.driver(url, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password), {disableLosslessIntegers: true});
let connection = driver.session()


async function go() {
    let res = await connection.run(`create (b:Banana {tag: 'test'}) return b,id(b) as id`, {});
    let b = res.records[0].get('b').properties
    console.log('b',b)
    let id = res.records[0].get('id')
    console.log('id',id)
    res = await connection.run(`MATCH (u) where id(u)=$id return u as id`, {id: id});
    console.log(res.records)
    let id2 = res.records[0].get('id').properties;
    console.log('id2',id2)
}

go().then(() => console.log('done')).catch((e) => console.log(e.message))
```

it gives the following output:

```
> node tools\test-id.js
b { tag: 'test' }
id 1858404
[ Record {
    keys: [ 'id' ],
    length: 1,
    _fields: [ [Node] ],
    _fieldLookup: { id: 0 } } ]
id2 { tag: 'test' }
done
```

Under 3.5.1 it does not work. The second statement returns no records:

```
> node tools\test-id.js
b { tag: 'test' }
id 1856012
[]
Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

BTW, the reason I need to do the get by id right after the create is that I am using an apoc trigger to add things to the node after creation, and apoc triggers apparently run after the object is created and returned, so I need the second get to see the transformed node.
But, for this distilled example I removed the trigger from my DB to ensure that it was not causing the issue